# Kibana health status is RED

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I am using AWS ELK(amazon managed elastic) and my Kibana health status  is red, trying to browse to the kibana URL i get "Kibana server is not ready yet".

I have tried to fix the problem but without luck, I think it all start when I changed my ELK settings from 1 availability zones with 1 instances to 2 Availability zones or another option is that I have streamed large amount of data in the last day.

As part of trials to fix the problem I returned to 1 availability zones with 1 instances but that didn't fix the problem.

Also I have Enabled the error logs and seen that I receive in cloudwatch:

> "publishing cluster state with version [68816] failed for the
>   following nodes"
>   "failed to connect to node"

Any help solving this problem will help.

More info(about my current setup):

> Domain status:Active
>       Elasticsearch version: 6.7
>       Availability zones:1
>       Instance type:r5.large.elasticsearch
>       Number of instances:1
>       Storage type:EBS
>       EBS volume type:General Purpose (SSD)
>       EBS volume size:1000 GB
>       Encryption at rest:Disabled
>       Node-to-node encryption:Disabled
>       Amazon Cognito for authentication:Disabled
>       Service software release:R20190724-P1

in the cluster health tab of the domain I can see:

> Cluster status:green
>       MasterReachableFromNode:green
>       AutomatedSnapshotFailure:green
>       KibanaHealthyNodes:red

and in the InvalidHostHeaderRequests I have about 60% of requests that are InvalidHostHeaderRequests out of ElasticsearchRequests (but I guess that is unrelated):

> CPUUtilization: is about 8%
>       JVMMemoryPressure: is about 20%
>       SysMemoryUtilization:98%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KibanaHealthyNodes is red possibly your kibana is down. Have you updated to AWS Elasticsearch v6.7 recently? Looks like the kibana needs to be restarted on the elasticsearch cluster for which AWS support team can help you with. Or in case you dont have support plan might be if you post on AWS forum someone from AWS can take a look and assist you with the same.

InvalidHostHeaderRequests will not cause the issue with kibana. AWS ES will throw this error when your application is trying to send the request on IPs of the nodes. Please check and use the domain endpoint in the request else this error will come up.

> > https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html